# Magento - Add index to table column using upgrade script

Tags: magento

Has any body tried adding index to a column in an already existing database table in magento way?

When I tried using

$table->addIndex('index_name', 'field_name', 'index_type'), it was not working.

Last I tried with normal ALTER TABLE query

$installer->run("ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX index_name(field_name)");

and I got it working.

The question is what might be the problem in doing it with magento table DDL functions?

Answer (score 9):

Magento allows you run SQL queries in two ways:

1. Using RAW sql queries
2. Using magento way

**Using RAW SQL queries**

You can run SQL queries directly. In your scenario,

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$sql=<<<SQLTEXT
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX index_name(field_name);
SQLTEXT;

$installer->run($sql);
$installer->endSetup();
```

It will add index in your table directly.

**Using magento way**

Using magento's way is quite complicated. It's like,

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$tableName = $installer->getTable('Module_name/Table_name');
// Check if the table already exists
if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName)) {
$table = $installer->getConnection();

$table->addIndex(
  $installer->getIdxName(
    'your_namespace/your_table',
    array(
      'column1',
      'column2',
      'column3',
    ),
    Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
  ),
  array(
    'column1',
    'column2',
    'column3',
  ),
  array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE)
)
$installer->endSetup();
}
```

Here pay attention with

```
 $tableName = $installer->getTable('Module_name/Table_name');
```

You should add your module name and table name carefully. Other wise it's not work. For more information go **[here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources)**

And don't forgot to add below things in your `config.xml` to get authentication of your db

```
<global>
...
<resources>
      <modulename_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Packagename_ModuleName</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </modulename_setup>
      <modulename_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </modulename_write>
      <modulename_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </modulename_read>
    </resources>
...
</global>
```

That's it. Please comment here if you have any question.

Comment: Please look into my question. I know both these methods and I successfully added index by raw sql method. When I tried magento way, the index was not added. My question is "What might be the problem that occur if we use magento way to add index to an already existing table?" In the code you wrote here, you are checking whether the table exists, and you placed the code inside != true condition. Funny

Comment: You didn't add full code of yours. So how can I find the problem .? That's what I have added this much. And thanks for highlighting the error.

Comment: Thank you. But I have done the same magento way. No luck and my index type was INDEX_TYPE_INDEX

Answer (score 2):

addIndex is method of connection object, not table object.
Something like below should do the trick. Check the source of Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql for all available methods of $installer->getConnection() object.

```
<?php 

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
if ($installer->tableExists($installer->getTable('module/table'))) {
    $installer->getConnection()
        ->addIndex(
            $installer->getTable('module/table'),
            $installer->getIdxName('module/table', array('column1', 'column2'), Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE),
            array('column1', 'column2'),
            Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
        );
}
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: I am facing the following issue while adding an index to my custom table using upgrade schema namespace/module_name/setup/Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface class not found

Answer (score 2):

I think the above examples are a bit overly complex. Here's a simple upgrade script to add a standard index to a table the "Magento" way. Replace 'foo/bar' with your Magento model to update, and 'baz' with the column you want to index.

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getTable('foo/bar');

if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($table)) {
    $installer->getConnection()->addIndex($table, 'baz', array('baz'));
}

$installer->endSetup();
```